# Applescript: how to click on a Favorite in a sidebar on a file dialog

Tags: applescript

I am trying to automate Preview to do a Move To... to a Favorite on the Sidebar.
I have clearly established that the object(s) on the sidebar are all on " row 9 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1"
In fact there are three objects that I can see:

1. "UI element xxxx"
2. static text xxxx of UI element xxxx" and
3. "image 1 of UI element xxxx"

In the simple script below, I've already opened Preview and navigated to the "Move To" file dialog by hand so that the "Move To" dialog is displayed.  I cannot get a click to do anything regardless of which object I try to click.

What am I doing wrong?

```
use AppleScript version "2.4" -- Yosemite (10.10) or lateruse scripting additions
set appname to "Preview"
```

```
tell application 
    appname activate
end tell
```

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process appname
        delay 1
        click static text 1 of UI element 1 of row 9 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1
        delay 1
    end tell
end tell
```

I expected the File Dialog to show the clicked Folder as if I had physically clicked it.  Nothing happens though.  I suspect a lack of focus, but I can't find a way to get the focus on the sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.
You (apparently) can not "click" on this object.

Instead of:

click static text 1 of UI element 1 of row 9 of outline 1 of scroll
area 1 of splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1

one needs to:

tell UI element 1 of row 9 of outline 1 of scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of sheet 1 of window 1

```
perform action "AXOpen"
```

end tell

Answer (score 0):

***GUI scripting***  *(it is what you are doing here)* is a very, very poor choice for a task that can be done without it. Here's how you can solve your problem:

```
-- Get alias reference to Favorites folder
set favoritesFolderAliasRef to path to favorites folder

-- Save the changes, Get alias reference of file of front document
tell application "Preview" to tell front document
    set documentPosixPath to path of it
    save it
end tell
set documentAliasRef to documentPosixPath as POSIX file as alias

-- Move the file of front document to Favorites
tell application "Finder"
    move documentAliasRef to favoritesFolderAliasRef
end tell
```

***NOTE***: You can indicate any other "favorites" folder instead of standard Favorite folder of Library folder of home.